Widow of a Cohen allowed to eat truma?
Does the widow of a Cohen keep the right to eat terumah if they had a child (Cohen) together?

See Rambam Trumot 6:12-14

The answer is yes, but complicated, as Mishnyos Yebamos 7:5-6 explain if a child survives or has surviving offspring (her grandson or granddaughter until she remarries), and also the widow did not remarry a non-cohen or did not become pregnant from a non-cohen. Gemara Yebamos 69b also brings baraisa, that only if the Cohen gives a woman a bill of divorce 1 hour before death she is prohibited to partake of teruma immediately.
To give a definite answer, one should study either perek 7 of Mishna, perek 7 of Gemara Yebamos, or as suggested in the comments Rambam Terumot (Heave Offerings) perek 8
